# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image

Tags: ios

I am getting the following ios crash

"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image1"

i though I had removed all references to "image1" but seemingly not.

Is there anyway I can search for any such references through out the project (even in the nib)?

Answer (score 2):

Typically when I see this it's because of a NIB connection.  The easiest way is to open the NIB in Interface Builder, select the Files Owner then the connections inspector (-> button in the utilities view).  There you can see all of the connections made to that object.  You can also walk through all of the items in your NIB with the connection inspector open until you find the offending element.

Answer (score 0):

To search in your nib/xib, right click on it and select "Open As --> Source Code"

Unfortunately, I've come across this error a couple of times where I was completely unable to get Xcode sorted out. I'd first try to manually get rid of it all from your code. If that fails, try closing and re-opening Xcode. If that fails, try a reboot. If that fails, I think you might need to start a new project and migrate your code over.

This is a bummer of a bug!

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried everything except the last option (recreate project). Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Not really, except you ought to be able to do a straight-up "add to project" for all of the files that aren't giving you errors. Then, you will need to manually create a replacement for the file that **IS** giving problems. After that, a copy and paste of .h/.m code should work. You can also probably get away with copying Interface Builder elements to help with the xib layout, but you'll have to re-create the IBOutlet/IBAction connections manually. At least, that's what I've found when I've had similar error messages.

Comment: seems all this was not needed, I was mistakenly pointing to the wrong view controller in my AppDelegate

Comment: I'd suggest pinning down the nib causing the error and going through all connections in it as @rob-booth suggested before opting to these solutions.