# Xcode, I moved my finished project and run it. It starts to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I finished my app which starts 2 months ago. Then I moved it to Dropbox with xcode opening it. Then try to run it.

It starts to report '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Mybutton.' This button is located at my root view.

I'm really getting crazy. This seems to be ruining my life. Anybody could provide me some ideas what's happening? I'm exhausted...

Great Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489017/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814389/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-picker Are you saying you missed all of these (and more?)

Comment: @borrrden: Thank you. I got my problem. I set root interface to a wrong one instead of leaving it blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with the xib connections. Check your connections first :

1. Open xib file .

2.click on first yellow box : files owner.

3.then click on the last arrow icon : show file inspector

check whether all the connections in the place or not . If there is any problem with the connection then you will find the ! icon in front of that item. just delete that connection .

Comment: Hi V-Xtreme, I checked it and find nothing wrong. Then I come up with the idea disconnect all of them. The result is obvious that log says there's no outlet for view. Then I just reconnect view, '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.' That's strange. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Ah I got my problem. I filled in a wrong main interface. This cause class-view mismatch.

Comment: thats nice ! have a nice coding .